# Auto-insert percentage values in my columns- Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to set a table which auto inserts percentage values into my last two columns that is present in the below given table. The code for the following table is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE CHIT_CHAT_BILLING
(
  BILL_NO NUMBER(3) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  CHAT_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  PRICE NUMBER(3) DEFAULT 0,
  PURCHASE_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  SERVICE_TAX NUMBER(4,1),
  VAT NUMBER(3,1) 
);
```

My insert query will be:

```
INSERT INTO 
CHIT_CHAT_BILLING (BILL_NO, CHAT_NAME, PRICE, PURCHASE_TIME)
VALUES (CHIT_CHAT_BILLING_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'PANI PURI','18','22-APR-2016 05:15:45 PM');
```

The values for `SERVICE_TAX` & `VAT` columns should be auto-inserted,
where **SERVICE_TAX = 12.5% of `PRICE`** & **VAT = 4.5% of `PRICE`**

***PS: I am using Oracle 11g Express Edition as my Database***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use virtual column for this:

```
CREATE TABLE CHIT_CHAT_BILLING
(
  BILL_NO NUMBER(3) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  CHAT_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  PRICE NUMBER(3) DEFAULT 0,
  PURCHASE_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  SERVICE_TAX AS(PRICE*0.125),
  VAT AS (PRICE*0.045)
);
```

*This feature supported only after 11g.